# TDD How to Assert that a property of a POCO is set within a method that is being tested

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, tdd, nsubstitute

We are creating a C# application using TDD and DI methodologies and NSubstitute.

We are writing a `CreateThing` method:

- `name` and `description` strings as parameters
- create a new `Thing` object
- set the `Name` and `Description` properties of `Thing` from the method parameters
- set the `Status` to `Active`
- pass the `Thing` to a method on another class (via constructor injection) for further processing

We know how to write a test for the call to the other class by using `Substitute.For` and `.Received()`.

How do we write tests for the `Thing` properties being set?

Comment: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/ section "checking calls to properties"

Comment: assert before and after the call

Comment: @WiktorZychla - the Thing is instantiated inside the method and is therefore not accessible in the test

Comment: If this is so then you are not following DI as you create a concrete instance instead of injecting it so that you could inject a mock.

Comment: But the `Thing` is a POCO and our create method accepts the values which are needed to create the POCO... Why/how would you inject this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Argument matchers](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/) namely Conditional matcher which looks like `Arg.Is<T>(Predicate<T> condition)`. Your matcher could look like:

```
anotherClass.Received().Process(Arg.Is<Thing>(thing => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(thing.Name)));
```

Full listing:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public virtual void Process(Thing thing)
    {
    }
}

public class CreateThingFactory
{
    private readonly AnotherClass _anotherClass;

    public CreateThingFactory(AnotherClass anotherClass)
    {
        _anotherClass = anotherClass;
    }

    public void CreateThing()
    {
        var thing = new Thing();
        thing.Name = "Name";
        _anotherClass.Process(thing);
    }
}

public class CreateThingFactoryTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CreateThingTest()
    {
        // arrange
        var anotherClass = Substitute.For<AnotherClass>();
        var sut = new CreateThingFactory(anotherClass);

        // act
        sut.CreateThing();

        // assert
        anotherClass.Received().Process(Arg.Is<Thing>(thing => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(thing.Name)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do actually know about that solution, BUT, isn't the test now testing 2 things? 1) That the other class is called AND 2) that it was called with a parameter where the Name was set. Everything that I have read/seen/heard about TDD says that this is a big no-no... A test should only ever test one "rule".

Comment: @Shevek, as far as I can tell Alexandr's answer meets your requirements. If you are concerned this is testing too much then perhaps consider changing your design to split up creation logic from the responsibility of coordinating creation and passing for "further processing". This could mean a new class that handles `Thing` creation and testing it returns a `Thing` with the required properties set. You can then test your original class correctly passes the result of the creation logic to the "further processing" class. Up to you as to whether you feel the added complexity helps or hinders.

Comment: @Shevek I agree with David. If you follow the TDD then you write tests first and won't encounter with current situation asking how to test. One more thing, there's no strict rule to assert only one thing in one test. Do whatever you think is logical and convenient in tests. Numerous of tests asserting similar things are difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thanks to both for your comments